# THT diode soldering

Tags: pcb, diodes, soldering, soldering-iron-station

If I apply more temperature and more time while soldering the diodes (in a leaded process). Will it fail eventually?

In case if I use a higher wattage soldering iron is it possible to fail?

Comment: what is the `it` that you are refering to?

Comment: It refers to the diode

Comment: thanks ... your post is unclear if you are referring to the diode or to the solder joint

Comment: Oxidized leads will take resist solder wetting and higher temp will make it oxidize faster.  Clean the surfaces with suitable abrasive then all you need is 15W ~20W or <320’C with flux. Pre-tinning each surface makes the solder flow much faster and unless your tip is extremely oxidized somewhere. diodes are rugged but Epoxy is not. Need more details

Comment: I am referring to the diode

Comment: Thanks Tony for you inputs. Diode I have failures is IN5408

Answer (score 0):

I assume you can eventually cause a diode to fail by using an uncontrolled high wattage soldering iron. It might be because the epoxy fails on a non-hermetic package, because rectifier dies are pretty rugged.

With modern temperature controlled irons higher wattage is not a disadvantage.

A skilled person can solder with an uncontrolled iron with no risk.

Comment: We are using a 80W iron

Comment: 40W is more appropriate for most electronics (better if it's temperature controlled by some means). 80W might be useful for soldering big things with a lot of heat loss or thermal mass, but not for general work. Inexpensive temperature controlled irons are available.

Comment: Yeah thanks. By the way I am using IN5408 . I have observed some failures . Just wanted to clear whether there is any problem in the soldering. I hope with your response there is no problem

Comment: There certainly could be. Soldering (especially with a high-power uncontrolled iron) involves skill. If the tip is properly tinned and the operator reasonably skilled, soldering a joint on a 1N5408 should take less than 1 second of contact. It's equally possible to damage the diode by carelessly bending the leads because they are very thick.

Comment: Yes I have checked the process. They are soldering for around 7-10 secs one side and around 5 secs for the other side